# The SELECT permission was denied

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query:

```
update sc 
set grade = 80
where grade = 90
```

results in this error:

> Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 1
>   The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sc', database 'student', schema 'dbo'.

I have typed this, and it get worked

```
grant UPDATE (grade) on sc to MyUserName
```

[image]

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Okay. Good for you. What was the question again? https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

My query:

```
update sc 
set grade = 80
where grade = 90
```

I need permission  to `update` and `select`, so I need to modify to

```
update sc
set grate = 80
```

or

```
grant UPDATE,SELECT (grade) on sc to MyUserName
```